Removing a shelf from closet organizer
How do I remove a cracked shelf(Wood) from a closet organizer with hidden screws.

Pictures and any other info could help here…

With the information provided, (Or the lack of it) the only suggestion is a hammer.

Other than a hammer there's explosives and trained termites, or a beaver.

I love the Beaver idea...but are you suggesting the animal or the young man from the 60s TV show?
